# Create OPL CPLEX tuple set by joining tuple sets with an additional condition on supersets related to joining rows

Tags: mathematical-optimization, cplex, opl

I have a tuple set in my model defined as follows:

```
tuple taskToolThTuple {string task; string tool; float throughput;};
{taskToolThTuple} taskToolTh = ...;
```

The data that populates this tuple set looks something like this:

```
taskToolTh = {
<"task1", "tool1", 10>
<"task1", "tool2", 11>
<"task1", "tool3", 12>
<"task2", "tool1", 8>
<"task3", "tool1", 9>
<"task3", "tool3", 14>
...
};
```

In other words, tasks require specific tools in order to be accomplished. Some tasks require 1 tool, some tasks require multiple tools.

Additionally, tasks can only be performed at workstations that contain all the tools needed for the task. Data on what tools are available at each station are in a separate tuple set:

```
tuple stationToolTuple {string station; string tool;};
{stationToolTuple } stationTool = ...;
```

The data looks something like this:

```
stationTool = {
<"station1", "tool1">
<"station2", "tool1">
<"station2", "tool3">
<"station3", "tool2">
<"station3", "tool3">
<"station4", "tool1">
<"station4", "tool2">
<"station4", "tool3">
...
};
```

What I need to do is create a new tuple set that includes station, tool, task, throughput but only adds a task to a station that can handle the task. For example, station 2 has tool 1 and tool 3 available, so tasks 2 and task 3 can both be performed there. However, task 1 requires tools 1, 2, and 3, so cannot be performed there.

If this syntax were allowed I think this would work:

```
{tuple} StationToolTaskThTuple = {string station; string tool; string task; float throughput;};
{StationToolTaskTuple} StationToolTask = {<s,to,ta,th> | <ta,to,th> in taskToolTh, <s,to> in stationTool : card({to2 | <ta,to2,th> in taskToolTh} inter {to2 | <s,to2> in stationTool}) == card({to2 | <ta,to2,th> in taskToolTh})};
```

The idea above is that I join any rows in taskToolTh and stationTool where tool matches, but only when the joining rows also satisfy the requirement that station *s* contains every tool *to* that is required for task *ta*. Unfortunately I get an error on this line ("Aggregate set is currently not supported for filter expressions.").

If possible, I'd like to do this without using the scripting language. Is this possible? If so, I'd appreciate help on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you can do some computation before in order not to do the slicing in the set computation.

For instance the following works:

.mod

```
tuple taskToolThTuple {string task; string tool; float throughput;};
{taskToolThTuple} taskToolTh = ...;

tuple stationToolTuple {string station; string tool;};
{stationToolTuple } stationTool = ...;

int c1[t in taskToolTh, s in stationTool ]=
card({s.tool | s2 in taskToolTh:t.task==s2.task } inter
 {t.tool | t2 in stationTool:t2.station==s.station});
int c2[t in taskToolTh, s in stationTool ]=
card({t2.tool |t2 in  taskToolTh:t2.task==t.task});

tuple StationToolTaskThTuple  
{string station; string tool; string task; float throughput;};
{StationToolTaskThTuple} StationToolTask = 

{<s,to_,ta,th> | <ta,to_,th> in taskToolTh, <s,to_> in stationTool 
: 
//card({to2 | <ta,to2,th> in taskToolTh} inter {to2 | <s,to2> in stationTool}) == card({to2 | <ta,to2,th> in taskToolTh})
c1[<ta,to_,th> , <s,to_>  ]==c2[<ta,to_,th> , <s,to_>  ]
};

execute
{
  writeln(StationToolTask);
}
```

.dat

```
stationTool = {
<"station1", "tool1">
<"station2", "tool1">
<"station2", "tool3">
<"station3", "tool2">
<"station3", "tool3">
<"station4", "tool1">
<"station4", "tool2">
<"station4", "tool3">
};

taskToolTh = {
<"task1", "tool1", 10>
<"task1", "tool2", 11>
<"task1", "tool3", 12>
<"task2", "tool1", 8>
<"task3", "tool1", 9>
<"task3", "tool3", 14>

};
```